# Invert predictions with Sklearn and Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I working with Tensorflow in Python.I made successful prediction and now I have problem with inversion on prediction. Namely I used MinMaxScaler from Sklearn and I normalize data with this lines of code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(df)
```

After successful fitting of model, I want to make inversion in data

```
# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)

# Shape of data
trainPredict.shape
(390, 7, 1)

testPredict.shape
(56, 7, 1)

# invert predictions
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
trainY= scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict_ = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])
```

After execution of last block of code I received this message:

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and fix last block of code ?

Comment: You are doing fit on your entire dataset (x and y), and you want to inverse just y. scikit-learn libraries expect input as `(n_samples,n_features)` and the second dimension should be the same you pass in `fit()` function. So, try to use a separate scaler for `y`.

Answer (score 1):

`MinMaxScaler` works with 2d data, where rows correspond to samples and columns are the features. They are scaled according to each feature's statistics: min, max. Your model outputs during prediction 3d array with shape[-1]=1, so you can use `np.squeeze` to solve that.

Also, I don't see any reason for inverse transforming the outputs of the model. It may be useful to do the inverse transform the training data if you need to get it back to its original unscaled form. Then it would be:

```python
trainX_inv = scaler.inverse_transform(trainX)
testX_inv = scaler.inverse_transform(testX)
```

Comment: I try this and again I have same error "Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2."